# Redmine migration error when installing DMSF plugin in upgrade install

Tags: installation, upgrade, redmine, rails-migrations, redmine-plugins

We're currently upgrading our Redmine installation from 3.3 to 3.4. We've successfully imported existing plugins except for [DMSF plugin](https://github.com/danmunn/redmine_dmsf).

The previous installation directory (still up and running) is

```
/home/username/usr/redmine/
```

and the new one

```
is /var/www/redmine_test/redmine-3.4.3/
```

When attempting to install the addon by running

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

the result is

```
Migrating redmine_dmsf (DMSF)...
== 20170422104901 MigrateDocuments: migrating = ================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/username/usr/redmine/files/dmsf/2017

/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
/var/www/redmine_test/redmine-3.4.3/plugins/redmine_dmsf/app/models/dmsf_file_revision.rb:145:in `disk_file'
/var/www/redmine_test/redmine-3.4.3/plugins/redmine_dmsf/db/migrate/20170422104901_migrate_documents.rb:31:in `block in up'
/home/username/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
...
```

Folder /home/username/usr/redmine/files does not belong to "username" user but to "root" (seems like the existing Redmine instance is running with sudo or something like that). Still, it worries me that this error is pointing to a previous installation folder and attempting to write in it.

Is the permissions issue for said directory the only thing causing this error? I'm not really looking forward to changing permissions and allowing the new instance to write inside the old one's directories.

If there is further explanation on this step in the DMSF plugin install process, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What happens if you dump your database to SQL file, then search for old folert name? /home/username/usr/redmine/files

Comment: Actually, there are occurences (about 2).
'\ndmsf_storage_directory: \"/home/josep/usr/redmine/files/dmsf\" and
"\ndmsf_index_database: \"/home/josep/usr/redmine/files/dmsf_index\"

Comment: Try replacing them in your db dump then re-import database, and test what you were doing previously...